# Azure AKS - Change location/region?

Tags: azure, kubernetes

Can I change location somewhere for a azure nodepool? 
I need to change it from US East to europe west.

Hope to hear some suggestions :)

Comment: Using Azure CLI can you try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#examples

Comment: It seems you cannot change the location for Azure node pool, if you want to change location, you just can recreate it in another location.

Answer (score 2):

Azure AKS Cluster act as a resource group, named MC_resourceGroupName_AKSClusterName_location. For your issue, you want to change the location for the node pool? It means you want to change the location of the resource group.

You can take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317498/changing-azure-resource-group-location). It seems you cannot change the location of a resource group, it means you cannot change the location for AKS node pool.

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you, please accept it as an answer so that it will help others looking for this.